# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when trying to write to json file

Tags: python, json, discord

The error I get is:

Ignoring exception in on_message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Lucas\python\lvlBot\main.py", line 34, in on_message
    users = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

```
import discord
import json
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '::')
#path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir(r'c:\Users\Lucas\python\lvlBot')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is running...")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    user[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = user[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = user[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await channel.send(channel, '{} har levlat upp till {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end

#print(path)
client.run('')
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure that the file you're trying to read is not empty? This is the error you would get in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For the first user, `users.json` is empty and therefore this causes Initially you will get `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:`. Probably it is worth checking whether

```
with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
    users = json.load(f)
```

returns `None`.

---

```
if not users:
    users = {} # or users = [] if you have a JSONArray
    await update_data(users, member)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your logic to just loading the json file.

Looking at your error message:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

you can see your error is that there is no content in your file ("character 0 should be a value").